# I have two scala projects - basically the same - one works and one does not. Can someone tell me why?

Tags: function, scala, text-based, mud

For class we have to make a test based game in which we move through a series of rooms like the old school text game Colossal Cave Adventure.

I began by defining functions for the different rooms so that when the directions are typed in  the room can be switched easily.

This following code works in the REPL most of the time, but I would like it to work every time:

```
def roomOne():Unit = {
println("You are currently in Room 1.")
println("There are 2 doors: North and West")
println("Which door would you like to go through?")

var input = readLine(">> ").toUpperCase match {
case "NORTH" => roomFour()
case "WEST" => roomNine()
case "EAST" => {
  println("You cannot go there.")
  roomOne()
}
case "SOUTH" => {
  println("You cannot go there.")
  roomOne()
  }
 }
}
def roomFour():Unit = {
println("You are currently in Room 4.")
println("There are 2 doors: East and South")
println("Which door would you like to go through?") 
}
def roomNine():Unit = {
println("You are currently in Room 9.")
println("There are 3 doors: North, East, and South")
println("Which door would you like to go through?")
}
def startGame():Unit = {
var input = readLine(">> ").toUpperCase match {
case "YES" => roomOne()
case "NO" => {
  println("When you are ready to begin please type \"yes\".")
  startGame()
}
}
}

println("**************************************************")
println("**************************************************")

println("Hello Mr. Doofenshmirtz. Are you ready to find the parts to create the Super DOOM-inator?")

startGame()
```

AND the following code DOES NOT WORK in the REPL at all:

```
def roomOne():Unit = {
println("You are currently in Room 1.")
println("There are 2 doors: North and West")
println("Which door would you like to go through?")

var input = readLine(">> ").toUpperCase match {
case "NORTH" => roomFour()
case "WEST" => roomNine()
case "EAST" => {
  println("You cannot go there.")
  roomOne()
}
case "SOUTH" => {
  println("You cannot go there.")
  roomOne()
}
}
}
def roomFour():Unit = {
println("You are currently in Room 4.")
println("There are 2 doors: East and South")
println("Which door would you like to go through?")

var input = readLine(">> ").toUpperCase match {
case "NORTH" => {
  println("You cannot go there.")
  roomFour()
}
case "WEST" => {
  println("You cannot go there.")
  roomFour()
}
case "EAST" => roomFive()
case "SOUTH" => roomOne()
}
}
def roomFive():Unit = {
println("You are currently in Room 5.")
println("There are 3 doors: East, South, and West")
println("Which door would you like to go through?")
}
def roomNine():Unit = {
println("You are currently in Room 9.")
println("There are 3 doors: North, East, and South")
println("Which door would you like to go through?")
}
def startGame():Unit = {
var input = readLine(">> ").toUpperCase match {
case "YES" => roomOne()
case "NO" => {
  println("When you are ready to begin please type \"yes\".")
  startGame()
}
}
}

println("**************************************************")
println("**************************************************")

println("Hello Mr. Doofenshmirtz. Are you ready to find the parts to create the Super DOOM-inator?")

startGame()
```

Can someone please help me out?  I have been trying different things all day and I can't seem to get it to work.  Why does the first one work some times and not always?  Why does the second one never work?  How do I get the second one to work each and every time I run it?

Thank you.

Comment: When it doesn't work what is the error you get?

Comment: This is what I get for the first one: http://pastebin.com/Ji0qVxc5

Comment: How exactly does it "not work"? Are they throwing errors? I just tried both of them in the REPL and they seemed to work as expected.

Comment: And this is what I get for the second one: http://pastebin.com/CHuFFzTh

Comment: After running them both, then running them again, they both work fine. Anyone know why this could be if it is working for you guys on the first try?

Comment: Theres a method missing in one of them.

Comment: Which one has a method missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the pastebin, the problem is probably with the way that you are pasting your code into the REPL. Try this:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

... paste stuff ...

... press Ctrl-d
```

Comment: I actually have two scala files that I load into the interpreter with:load.  I tried pasting that way and it works every time.  Do you know how to fix it with the load method?

Comment: No, but I've sometimes found the :load command to be a bit buggy. You might have better luck passing the file with the `-i` option: `scala -i myfile.scala`

Comment: In addition to what Chris B says, I'd also recommend using a build tool in addition to the REPL. I personally use [Scala IDE for Eclipse](http://scala-ide.org/), which integrates everything automatically. There's a steep learning curve, but also a big payoff.